# Npm: Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined

Tags: node.js, git, npm, travis-ci

On project we use travis

on my last PR i've got an error:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! git clone --template=/home/travis/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/*****/***-global.git /home/travis/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-****-***-global-git-1c65c4d0
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-40-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/home/travis/.nvm/v0.10.38/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.38
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/travis/build/*****/*****-auth/npm-debug.log
The command "npm install" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

At dev machine all works fine
I tried set source with git+https / git://
try to set the same node / npm version for travis
i even try to set

```
os:
  - osx
```

The same

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fixed in npm version 2.7.5, as it is written in changelog  https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md, #7746 bug fix. Try to update npm.

Answer (score 2):

This bug was fixed at npm 2.7.5

So my way to resolve problem was add to .travis.yml

```
before_install:
  - "npm install -g npm@^2.7.5"
```